# Nested Loops to create a pattern

Tags: python, loops, nested

How could I use Nested Loops to create the following pattern?

```
111111
11111
1111
111
11
1
```

So far i have this and i seem to be stuck.

```
def main():
stars = "******"
for x in range (1,7):
    print(stars)

    for y in range (1,1):
        stars = stars.replace("*"," ")
main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace just 1 star in the inner loop:

```
stars = "******"
for x in range(6): 
    stars = stars.replace("*","1")
    print(stars)
    for y in range(1): # need range(1) to loop exactly once
        stars = stars.replace("1","",1)
```

Output:

```
111111
11111
1111
111
11
1
```

If you actually want stars:

```
stars = "******"
for x in range(6):
    print(stars)
    for y in range(1):
        stars = stars.replace("*","",1)
```

Output:

```
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

The last arg to [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) is count where *only the first count occurrences are replaced.* So each time we only replace a single character.

If you have to uses the stars variable and replace then the code above will work, if you just need nested loops and to create the pattern, you can loop down from 5 and use `end=""` printing once in the inner loop:

```
for x in range(5, -1, -1):
    print("1" * x, end="")
    for y in range(1):
        print("1")
```

Again the same output:

```
111111
11111
1111
111
11
1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Knew it couldn't be hard.

Comment: The inner loop basically is no loop... it runs only once, therefore you could just as well leave it out and execute its content directly.

Comment: @swenzel. then it would not be nested, read the question. Whether a loop runs once or 1000000 times it is still a loop

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, It formally is a loop, I agree. That's why I said *basically*. But since it is predetermined that it runs only once I think it is cheating and only there so you can say: "It is nested". Please don't take that as an offense, it's just meant as criticism :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def main(symbol, number):
    for x in reversed(range(number)):
        s = ""
        for y in range(x+1):
            s += symbol
        print s

main("1", 6)
```

You can give arguments one *symbol* (**Example - '1','*'**) and *number* (**Example - '5 for *****'** to start with)

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing all the stars in the string with the replace method, meaning you would online print one line of start. You could use the substring method for a better result.

Answer (score 0):

Check answer of **Padraic Cunningham** with **Nested Loop**.

**Without Nested Loop:**

1. Create Count list by range method and reverse method of list.
2. Iterate list and print 1 multiple of count.

code:

```
counters = range(1, 7)
counters.reverse()
for i in counters:
    print "1"*i
```

Output:

```
111111
11111
1111
111
11
1
```

Comment: That is not a nested loop

Comment: @PadraicCunningham:  yes correct. Again I not read question carefully. Apology. But  we directly use `stars = stars.replace("*","",1)`  because every time second `for loop` will run only one time. and Up-vote you +1

Comment: Yep, it is simple to do it in a single loop, I think the challenge was doing it in two loops and using replace.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Have question, `stars= '******'` then I do `stars.replace("", "V")` then I got `V*V*V*V*V*V*V` Why `V` in output?

Comment: You are replacing an empty string with V.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: yes, means empty string is present after every character in the target string. Have any link related to it?

Comment: All I could get was an old thread https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-May/065158.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you're requesting a nested loop, I guess this is just a training exercise and it is not important how efficient it is.
Therefore let me propose a solution with a 'proper' inner loop and without reversed ranges:

```
def triangle(x, c='1'):
    for i in range(x):
        line = ''
        for _ in range(i, x):
            line += c
        print(line)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the same output using a simple approach, as Python supports `*` operator on Strings which returns a string with repeated occurrences.

```
character = "1"   #You can change it to "*"
for i in range(6, 0, -1):
    print character*i
```

Output:

```
111111
11111
1111
111
11
1
```